# PNG with XMP meta being blocked by the server

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmp

I have a codeigniter application and when I try to upload a PNG file with XMP meta it gets blocked by the server. Just wanted to know if anyone else has ever had that problem with AWS EC2

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.

AWS XSS security filter was blocking the request when the PNG contained XMP meta. I just deactivated the XSS filter as it was not needed.

Comment: What AWS XSS filter, are you using AWS WAF ?

Comment: @JamesDean yes I am using AWS WAF

Comment: You should mention these details in the initial description so that people can help you.

Comment: @JamesDean didn't know that WAF was causing the issue when I posted the question. But yeah I get your point and I will try to include more information in future questions.